# Are dependencies themselves compiled when my project is compiled?

Tags: java, compilation

When I compile a Java project, are the dependencies of the project themselves compiled at that point? Or, are dependencies using pre-compiled Java class files?

Comment: How are those dependencies added to your project? If they are another project, chances are they're getting compiled as well. If they are JARs you added or imported via maven/gradle, they're pre-compiled already.

Comment: They are imported via maven/gradle.

Answer (score 2):

Only the code you have locally is compiled, when you compile.

Code you reference is already available in compiled form, in a jar.

Answer (score 0):

They're *resolved*. If the dependencies are part of the same Maven project or are imported into a managed IDE workspace, then they will be compiled and then placed on the classpath as part of your build. Most of the time, however, they will be downloaded as jars from some repository. (Note that dependency jars necessarily contain `.class` files; they might consist solely of resource files instead, such as [WebJars](https://www.webjars.org).)